# Hive: How to test and find for null map entries?

Tags: hive

If using the map type in a Hive table, how can I test for a null entry (key exists, but value is null)?

With table:

```
 test1 (id string, m map<string, string>)
```

I have a few entries that look like this:

```
id1 {"b":"B","c":null} 
id2 {"b":"B"}
```

If I run the query:

> select * from test1 where m["c"] is null;

I will get both rows back since expression evaluates true each time.

How can I test between key exists and value is null?

Comment: so yes, I added my own answer, but looking for feedback and/or other solutions

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've come up with 2 solutions

To find the rows where the map actually contains a specific key and its is null:

```
select * from test1 where array_contains(map_keys(m),'c') and m["c"] is null;
```

To find any key where the value is null:

```
select id,k from test1 LATERAL VIEW explode(m) et as k,v where v is null;
```